# What does "Static factories returned object need not exist" mean?

Tags: java

While reading "Effective Java" J.Bloch came across this statement

> A fifth advantage of static factories is that the class of the returned object need not exist when the class containing the method is written.

What does it mean?  Can someone explain it with some examples ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the API of your static factory method can return an interface type, of which the implementation won't be written or generated until later.

As an example:

```
public static MyInterface getMyInterfaceInstance() {
    //load instance dynamically and return it.
}
```

In this case, the factory method only needs the `MyInterface` interface to exist when it's being compiled. The actual implementation can be loaded dynamically at runtime in many ways, including:

- Creating a proxy object
- Reflection (configurable implementation class name loaded at runtime)
- Looking up a [service loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

In particular, the last two options simply mean that the implementation class can be written in a different module (and many modules can provide an implementation of the interface), and these implementation classes will be discovered at runtime - which makes it possible for the static factory method to be written before the actual implementation class.

Comment: One question tho, shouldn't there be at least an implementation of that interface? I mean one has to return something from a method with that return type, no? And since `MyInterface` has no implementation, it will cause an error, unless one returns null. I couldn't really wrap my head around it.

Comment: @MensurQulami The point is not about there not being an implementation. It's about separating the implementation from the factory. The code with `getMyInterfaceInstance()` can be released weeks before the code that implements `MyInterface`. If the implementation of this method were, for example, `return (MyInterface) Class.forName(System.getProperty("my.interface.implementation.class")).newInstance()`, then the class implementing `MyInterface` doesn't need to be compiled at the same time as this static factory. Of course an implementing class will be needed (but only at runtime)

Comment: Thank you so much, for detailed explanation.